# Emoji in Netgear Wi-Fi network name: "Character is not allowed in SSID."

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, netgear-router

I'm attempting to change my Netgear router's SSID to a string containing emoji characters: `"Wi-Fi "`.

When I change the `Name (SSID)` field to a new value containing an emoji, the router login page displays the error:

> [www.routerlogin.com](http://www.routerlogin.com) says
> Character is not allowed in SSID.

I have used emoji in the SSID of wireless networks from other router brands including Apple and UniFi.

Are emoji really not available in Netgear SSID strings? If so, where is this confirmed by Netgear?

Is there any way to force the router to use an emoji-containing name?

Comment: The following link talking about how to add emoji in Netgear router's SSID, you could have a look: [Emojify your Wi-Fi (Netgear R6300 edition)](https://alexplescan.com/posts/2016/08/16/emojify-your-wifi-netgear-r6300/)

Answer (score 6):

> Please refer to the following steps:
>
> 1. Go to your Netgear admin panel and craft your beautiful emoji-enriched SSID.
> 2. Open up the developer console.
> 3. Override the validation function by typing in *window.checkData = function() { return true; }* (and then pressing Return)
> 4. Craft emoji-enriched SSID.
> 5. Save.

For more details, please refer to the following link:

[Emojify your Wi-Fi (Netgear R6300 edition)](https://alexplescan.com/posts/2016/08/16/emojify-your-wifi-netgear-r6300/)

Comment: The function is called `window.check_ssid` in the newer models, but, sadly, the router barfs with status `400` when the js makes the request to save the fancy SSID ;-(